# How to fix "Call to undefined method KeycloakGuard\KeycloakGuard::attempt" using laravel package

Tags: php, laravel, keycloak

I am using robsontenorio/laravel-keycloak-guard laravel package to connect my laravel application with keycloak for session management.I have followed the settings as provided in 
the GitHub https://github.com/robsontenorio/laravel-keycloak-guard. 
But still i am receiving the connection error.

These are the setting I used in `config/keycloak` file to connect with keycloak.

**For 'realm_public_key' i used the id provided under client registration menu**

```
  'realm_public_key' => env('KEYCLOAK_REALM_PUBLIC_KEY', '1897f935-eec2-4fa5-a1f6-6fb71a8ec881'),

  'load_user_from_database' => env('KEYCLOAK_LOAD_USER_FROM_DATABASE', true),

  'user_provider_credential' => env('KEYCLOAK_USER_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL', 'username'),

  'token_principal_attribute' => env('KEYCLOAK_TOKEN_PRINCIPAL_ATTRIBUTE', 'preferred_username'),

  'append_decoded_token' => env('KEYCLOAK_APPEND_DECODED_TOKEN', false),

  'allowed_resources' => env('KEYCLOAK_ALLOWED_RESOURCES', null)
```

I am using Laravel 5.7 with Keycloak 5.0.0

Can anyone help me out to fix this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: did you use that Keylock class in your controller ??

Comment: But I can't find the class name settings in the documentation.Where should I use it for my authentication to work